# does anyone knows how to install mysql on ubuntu ec2 instance

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04

i tried it several times but there are always an error can anyone give me the codes which I can run and try based on apt-get tool

Comment: You didn't mention how you tried it. You didn't mention what errors you got. Have a -1 until you improve it and write a meaningful question.

Comment: hey bro, now I have mentioned my problem so can u now provide me some solution for not able to run mysql

Comment: root@ip-172-31-11-54:~# mysql ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: i have used the below codes for installation

Comment: you are not using password!  use `mysql -u -p` and enter your password on the prompt

Comment: root@ip-172-31-11-54:~# mysql -u -p
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '-p'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
root@ip-172-31-11-54:~#

Comment: see this @Nick now I did in your way then also its not working

Comment: hey both of u I have tried mysqld and if it worked or not I cant undersand plzz help me outjust see  this

Comment: root@ip-172-31-11-54:~# mysqld
root@ip-172-31-11-54:~# mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install MySQL

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

During the installation you will be prompt for a root password.

Configure MySQL

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Test your MySQL installation

```
mysqladmin -p -u root version
```

Or you can use an image that has MySQL pre installed and configured for you.

[MySQL powered by Bitnami](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01M0RA8RN)

Comment: I just installed it but not able to run MySQL ?

Comment: Please attach the error log or MySQL logs. They are located on `/var/log/mysql.err`  and `/var/log/mysql.err`

Comment: root@ip-172-31-11-54:~# mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
see this  @Nick

Comment: root@ip-172-31-11-54:~# cd /var/log
root@ip-172-31-11-54:/var/log# ls
alternatives.log  cloud-init.log         fsck      mysql
apt               cloud-init-output.log  kern.log  syslog
auth.log          dist-upgrade           lastlog   unattended-upgrades
btmp              dpkg.log               lxd       wtmp
root@ip-172-31-11-54:/var/log# tail -n 100 /var/log/mysql.err
tail: cannot open '/var/log/mysql.err' for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: there is no such file or directory

Comment: @rahulgupta cd into the MySQL folder and check the logs.

Also, checked my updated answer, you can use a free image that has MySQL already configured and installed for you

Comment: bro @Nick I cant paste that error.log file here because its very lengthy appr 944 bytes and this stack overflow is not allowing me to paste that files content

Comment: Paste the last 10-15 lines. Or use the marketplace image that already has MySQL installed

Comment: 2017-09-24T14:15:19.626312Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we $
2017-09-24T14:15:19.632900Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Tab$
2017-09-24T14:15:19.633176Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty$

Comment: 2017-09-24T14:15:25.055945Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (r$
2017-09-24T14:15:25.055984Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 ($
2017-09-24T14:15:25.210812Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value i$
2017-09-24T14:15:25.212246Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.19-0ubuntu0.1$
2017-09-24T14:15:25.216052Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available

Comment: 2017-09-24T14:15:25.216069Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomi$
2017-09-24T14:15:25.216073Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-09-24T14:15:25.216078Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence($
2017-09-24T14:15:25.216082Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-09-24T14:15:25.216085Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-09-24T14:15:25.216308Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-09-24T14:15:25.216400Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-09-24T14:15:25.217744Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total si$

Comment: plzz have a look on them and sorry for late reply,and I wanna say that if it wont happen then only ill switch to marketplace but I don't think it this current wont work

Comment: Looks like a corrupt install. @rahulgupta. I suggest creating a fresh instance and trying again or using the AMI. I just tested it and it worked

Comment: thnx @Nick for reply but I successfully executed mysqlserver by using command  #mysql -u root -p

Comment: bro can u help me out in connecting my instance mysql server with my windows os system actually I want to connect my android studio app with mysql server on ec2 instance to insert some data using that android app